# Using GWT calendar in GAE project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm working on gae project/ I have a servlet that process data and store it in JDO. Now I want to add new page with ui. Main ui element is calendar. What is the simplest way to do it? Using servlets, gwt, java calendar or what?
Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, you need to specify what you mean by simplest.

If you already have GWT setup, building it in GWT would be easy, if you want to stick to plain servlets, setting up a JSP page with the calendar on is fairly simple.

In the JSP case, you can use java.util.Calendar to construct your calendar, in GWT you might need to look at com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil.

Comment: I haven't GWT setup, can you give some links to information about it?

Comment: And some articles about jsp & calendar are interesting for me too

Comment: JSP is the easiest to setup: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps